# Strange behavior of setColorFilter()

Tags: android, android-activity

I have noticed a strange behavior of setColorFilter(). I have some buttons in my activity and when the user clicks on one of them, if a certain condition is true I want to set a green background to it, otherwise red. This doesn't work. However in another method, where there isn't any condition, the same statement works.
I have this problem only on ICS while on Lollipop all works well. I solved this by using a drawable to set the background, but I would like to understand why there is this problem.
First method:

```
 private void setButtons() {

    buttonList = new ArrayList<>();

    /*buttons initialization*/

    for (int i = 0; i < btnNumber; i++) {

        buttonList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Button btn = (Button) v;
                String buttonText = btn.getText().toString();

                if (buttonText.equals(getAnswer())) {
                //set background to GREEN
                btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.GREEN), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

                } 
                else {
                //set background to RED
                btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.RED), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Second method in the same class:

```
 private void revealAnswer() {
    String answer = getAnswer();
    for (int i = 0; i < btnNumber; i++) {
        Button currentBtn = buttonList.get(i);
        String currentText = (String) currentBtn.getText();
        if (currentText.equals(answer)) {
            //set background to GREEN
            buttonList.get(i).getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.GREEN), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside-  red/green for wrong/right is a bad combo.  Its one of the worlds most common forms of color blindness, a large percentage of men can't see the difference between them.

Comment: When you say it isn't working, is it not showing any change or is it showing the wrong color?  In the first case I'd assume you weren't passing the conditional.  In the second, I'd wonder if the old filter isn't being removed, just a new one applied.

Comment: It is not showing any change. Also the condition is correct, I've already tested it. Instead of "something" there is a method that returns String, I forgot to change it, sorry.